# Закрыть порт 8080 на фронте докер + nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, rewrite

Подскажите как закрыть порт на котором работает бекенд, чтобы он был недоступен из фронта.
Используется окружение докер сервер nginx
docker-compose конфиг по nginx

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    links:
      - php-fpm
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
```

Конфиг nginx для бекенда в докер контейнере

```
server {
listen 8080;
index index.php index.html;
root /var/www/public;

#ssl on;
#ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
#ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;

index index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}

location /docs {
    try_files $uri $uri/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
}
```

Так же я создал nginx сервер для проксирования на фронте выглядит следующим образом

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
}
}
```

Как сделать чтобы по запросу domain.com:8080 ничего не отдавалось на фронте. но при этом чтобы сервер работал на это 8080 порту ?

Comment: А вы уверены что на внешнем интерфейсе порт бэкенда открыт? Киньте ссылку выданную этой командой. `netstat -t4lpn | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: @Oxyd https://termbin.com/lq53

Comment: Я тут вообще не вижу 8080-го порта. Он у вас живой вообще?

Comment: @Oxyd а как же такое может быть тогда? Сайт то физически открывается по адресу с портом 8080 http://pm-webdev.top:8080/ и так же открывается по без него

Comment: Как правильно тогда сделать? Нужно открыть порт 8080 и отключить маппинг в докер файле?

Comment: Вы команду на самом хосте, где у вас контейнеры лежат, запускали?

Comment: Да, конечно на нем, обычная чистая впска со стеком lemp

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103843/discussion-between-pavel-and-oxyd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Закрыть порт можно правилами iptables. Так как приложения работают в докере и имеют свои, хоть и виртуальные, сетевые интерфейсы,сетевой трафик идёт не через цепочку INPUT, а через цепочку FORWARD, соответственно правило для iptables выглядит например так: `iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP` Скрипты сохранения можно [взять тут](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119393/how-to-save-rules-of-the-iptables).

Comment: Да супер, все получилось :)